# Spivak: What justifies subbing in Taylor polynomials of parts of a function expression and then ignoring any terms involving remainders?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The following problem is from Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 5. (b) Estimate the solutions of the equation $$2x^2=x\sin{x}+\cos^2{x}\tag{1}$$

The solution manual uses the following third degree Taylor polynomials at $0$

$$P_{3,0,\sin}=\sin{x}=x+\bar{R}(x)$$

$$P_{3,0,\cos}=\cos{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R(x)$$

and subs them into $(1)$ to obtain

$$2x^2=x(x+\bar{R}(x))+(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R(x))^2$$

$$=x^2+1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{4}+2(1-\frac{x^2}{2})R(x)+R(x)^2+x\bar{R}(x)$$

Then, "ignoring terms involving $R$ and $\bar{R}$ gives the equation

$$x^4-8x^2+4=0$$

which we can solve for $x^2$ and then $x$.

I've learned about the Taylor theorem. When we use a Taylor polynomial to approximate a function, we are in effect ignoring the remainder term in the Taylor theorem.

In the problem above however, we have a function $x\sin{x}+\cos^2{x}$ and instead of computing its Taylor polynomial we are computing Taylor polynomials for parts of the function expression, namely $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$, and then ignoring all terms involving remainders.

What justifies this?

Comment: The question asks you to _estimate_. And for $x$ close enough to $0$, the remainders $\bar{R}, R$ are very close to $0$ (as the largest terms in the remainders are cubic and quadratic in $x$, respectively). This means that sin and cos are well approximated by $x$ and $1 - x^{2}/2$ when $x$ is small enough. You can formalise this a bit more using the [big-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [little-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) notations.

Comment: Intuitively it seems to be somewhat clear that we could make these substititions. But I am a bit confused because usually there is a theorem or an example in the theoretical part of chapters in this book that gives an idea on how to solve the end-of-chapter problems. In this case, I don't see any theorem saying that if we approximate different functions within a function composition we will have a good approximation of the composition itself.

Comment: On the other hand, it is true that I can estimate the size of both remainders, so I can actually obtain an estimate of the size of the terms being ignored. Especially if I know that the solution is such that $|x|<1$ which is the case in this problem (though I am not sure how the solution manual solution knows this a priori).